# How to use Selenium executable jars and integrate them with Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins and Selenium but the problem is all I have are executable jars, testng.xml, and run.bat to run the test suit and I have to upload these files to SVN and then integrate them with Jenkins. I know how to use these on a local machine by creating a freestyle project in Jenkins but how is it possible to do the same thing by having files in SVN instead of a local machine? (again We don't have the code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Jenkins` file. Like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("Tests") {
      steps {
        git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", url: 'http://gitUrl/tests.git'
        sh 'java -jar pathToJar/your.jar'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Put it in the same repo where all of your test jars are located. After that, you need to create pipeline job on Jenkins with only one configuration `Pipeline script from SCM` and provide GIT link to your repo with the tests, where created `Jenkinsfile` is located.